# How to change the front end language for existing Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

How to change the front end language for a WordPress site? I want to keep my back end as it is, only change the front end language.

While I searched, I found may be I have to modify the .mo file.

More details please?

Comment: You don't need to use `[Wordpress]` in your question title provided you properly tagged your question with the `wordpress` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this plugin can help :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xlanguage/

Comment: Thanks SpyrosP. This plug-in offers many features, it may solve my issue.